# Prove that the following are equivalent.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Let $(V,d)$ be a metric space and $A \subset V$.  Define $f \colon V \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = 1$ if $x\in A$ and $f(x) = 0$ if $x\notin A$. Prove the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $A$ is open and closed.
> 2. $f$ is continuous.

I have the feeling that i have to prove that $f(A)$ is also open and closed but I am not quite sure.

Comment: It's usually written *the following are equivalent* rather than *equal.*  It means you need to prove (1) $\implies$ (2) and (2) $\implies$ (1).  Neither of them is necessarily true.

Comment: I think there's a mistake in your typing, the way it's defined $f(x) = 1$ for all $x$.

Comment: There was thanks and it good to know the proper way of saying it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean that  $f(x) = 0$ if $x\notin A$.

In that case you probably have to use the definition of $f continuous$ in a metric set. $f$ is continuous iff for all open (resp closed) set $B$, $f^{-1}(B)$ is open (resp closed).

$(1) \implies (2)$:

If $A$ is open and closed, then let $B$ an open set of $R$.

If $0, 1 \in B$ then $f^{-1}(B) = V$ which is open.

If $0, 1 \notin B$ then $f^{-1}(B) = \varnothing$ which is open.

If $0\in B$ and $1 \notin B$ then $f^{-1}(B) = V\backslash A$

which is open because A is closed.
If $1\in B$ and $0 \notin B$ then f^{-1)(B) = A$ which is open .

So $f$ is continuous.

$(2) \implies (1)$:

If $f$ is continuous, then $A = f^{-1}(\{1\})$ is closed because ${1}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$. Moreover,  $A = f^{-1}(]-1/2;1/2[)$ is open because $]-1/2;1/2[$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Is {1} always open and closed in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ comes generally with the usual distance $|.|$, and with this distance, $\{1\}$ is closed but not open (you can not find any ball included in $\{1\}$. So it is not always open (but always closed because it is a singleton).

Comment: {1} is closed but not open in $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

**hint for $2)\implies 1) $**

$f $ continuous and $\{1\} $ is closed $\implies f^{-1}(\{1\}) =A$ is closed.

$f $ continuous and $\{0\} $ closed $\implies f^{-1}(\{0\})=V\backslash A $ closed $\implies A $open.